# Check windows processes by name

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, process, monitor

I'm looking for something that can be run on 1 machine to monitor the processes of another machine in Windows, and notify (email?)

Basically, Server A is running "Application.exe" and Server A reboots - I need Server B to be able to spot that the application "Application.exe" is no longer running on Server A and alert me, possibly by email.

I tried to do something in ruby, but the only ruby I can use on these servers is JRuby and I didn't get very far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, everything you need you will find on this page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692846.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks quite interesting, I'll check that out! Thanks!